# Configure an Intel AGN 5100 wireless card under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, wireless-networking

I have a new Lenovo T500, with Ubuntu 8.04 LTS installed.

The wireless card isn't working - sometimes it detects the wireless networks, but most of the times it can't. I have tried using the network icon, but it still can't find any network.

`lspci` yielded this:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 4237
```

Googling it didn't help much. Any Ideas?

**EDIT**: I'm having trouble installing the [Intel Linux Wireless](http://intellinuxwireless.org/) from the [wlwifi project](http://intellinuxwireless.org/?p=iwlwifi). Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,

Udi

Comment: BTW any idea what the model of your network card is?

Comment: Intel AGN 5100.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install different drivers, that support it better.

Perhaps look at [Intel Linux Wireless](http://intellinuxwireless.org/) for the drivers you need

---

Or try a different [network connection manager like Wicd](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/wicd-wired-and-wireless-network-manager-for-ubuntu.html)

Wicd is an open source wired and wireless network manager for Linux which aims to provide a simple interface to connect to networks with a wide variety of settings.

[image]

Comment: I'll try the second option - the lspci insinuates it is a driver, not connection manager, problem. Thanks!

Comment: I switched it around if that's the most likely correct answer